# What does "a cannot be resolved" mean in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to program an appointment program and I'm a beginner at java. I'm using VScode.

the code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {                  
        a.menuPrint(); //Prints menu to begin 
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
a cannot be resolved

 at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

The `a` variable is supposed to print the menu. I don't know why it can't be resolved. Are there any reasons why?

Comment: What is `a`? Where is it defined and initialized?

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting. Tip: Use a search engine of your choice with `site:stackoverflow.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information here to decide. Typically "cannot be resolved" means that you are using an object that is not declared in the block where it is being used and it is not global.

In your example, variable `a` is being used in the `main` method. If `a` is not a global variable, that explains the problem: inside the method body, `a` is not defined (cannot be resolved to whatever type that variable is).

To fix:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    WhateverClass a = new WhateverClass();
    a.menuPrint();
}
```

Comment: thank you, this helped.

Comment: @tech12342 I don't know if you can click the checkmark by my answer. If you can, I will appreciate it if you dos as long as it helped you solve your problem.